# How do I parse multiple strings from HTML using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I need to parse this HTML code with Nokogiri, but save "Piso en Calle Antonio Pascual" in one variable and "Peñiscola" in another variable.

```
<h1 class="title g13_24">
        Piso en  Calle Antonio Pascual
        <span class="title-extra-info">Peñíscola</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-HTML)
  <h1 class="title g13_24">
    Piso en  Calle Antonio Pascual
    <span class="title-extra-info">Peñíscola</span>
  </h1>
HTML

h1 = doc.at_css('h1.title')
str1 = h1.children[0].text.strip
# => "Piso en  Calle Antonio Pascual"
str2 = h1.at_css('.title-extra-info').text.strip
# => "Peñíscola"
```

But frankly, the Nokogiri documentation would have told you the same.

Comment: For the record, the addition of any formatting will cause this to break, while my method will be unaffected.

Comment: @pguardiario: What kinds of changes do you mean?

Comment: Any small change to the first line - bold, italic, anchor, etc. If you want to survive those you have to do it my way. And that's no joke :P

Comment: @pguardiario: Maybe I'm too stupid, but I still don't see what you mean. Can you give an example? Do you mean like wrapping the text in some other element? That wouldn't be valid HTML anymore, I guess (but after all, the extra `<span>` isn't as well).

Comment: For example one day they decide to make 'Calle Antonio Pascual' italics. They wrap it in i tags and your script stops picking it up.

Comment: @pguardiario: Probably they'd rather add a CSS rule to style that `h1`'s contents. But hell, you never know. Scraping is never future-proof. They could just as well remove the whole header.